# forkjoin not returning response

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a method for executing requests.the requests are fired but Iam not able to get response.

```
saveData(bannerDataFiles: BannerDataFile[]) {
        const bannerObservables = [];
        bannerDataFiles.forEach(bannerDataFile => {
            bannerObservables.push(this.uploadService.upload(bannerDataFile.file, '/original/banner/')
                 .pipe(catchError(err => of(err)))
                .pipe(mergeMap((fileName) => {
                    bannerDataFile.bannerData.link = fileName['Location'];
                    return this.http.post(this.url, bannerDataFile.bannerData);
                })));
        });
        return Observable.forkJoin(...bannerObservables).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });

    }
```

Comment: You're returning a `Subscription` object instead of an Observable because you're calling `subscribe()`. You probably just want to use `return Observable.forkJoin(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.All the observables needs to be completed for forkjoin to complete.In my case observable in uploadService wasn't complete.after I emitted complete I was able to get response.

Answer (score 0):

Forkjoin waits for everything to be completed. Check your bannerObservables or uploadService if its working properly, is it complete.